# Using WHERE on grouped rows after UNION statement

Tags: mysql

I have a database schema with two tables, song and edited_song. These tables are identical, except for one extra column in edited_song called deleted. The edited_song-table contains a reference to the id in the song-table. I want to find all the songs which aren't deleted.

I have a UNION-statement in which I GROUP on the id of the result of two SELECT-statements. I want to exclude results where the deleted column has the value 1. An example of the setup can be seen here.

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists song
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
title varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
CREATE TABLE if not exists editedsong
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
  title varchar(255),
  deleted tinyint(1),
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);

INSERT INTO song (id, title) VALUES
(1, 'Born in the USA');


INSERT INTO editedsong (id, title, deleted) VALUES
(1, 'Born in the USA', 1);
```

And the query is here:

```
SELECT * FROM
  ((SELECT *, 0 AS deleted FROM song WHERE id=1)
UNION
  (SELECT * FROM editedsong WHERE id=1)) AS song
WHERE song.deleted!=1
GROUP BY song.id
```

The UNION-statement is used instead of a join as there is a LOT of text in these two tables and a join results in writing to disk. This is a simplified form of the real query, but it reproduces the problem I'm experiencing. I would expect the query to yield no results as the GROUP BY should preserve the first row and throw away all following. Why doesn't it do this? Is it because the WHERE is executed before the GROUP BY? If it is, what is a good way to overcome this problem?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5cdb6c/3

Comment: Thanks for providing the fiddle, but questions need to stand alone.

Comment: Please read up on what `GROUP BY` does and doesn't do. You have become confused by a misfeature in MySQL's implementation of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I have edited the question to fit with the "stand alone"-requirement. I will also read up on `GROUP BY` as you suggested. Thanks for helping!

Comment: For future reference [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) is the documentation for the MYSQL "misfeature".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the code in the SQLFiddle doesn't work is that the `WHERE` clause is excluding the deleted record from editedsong before the `GROUP BY` is executed.

You can use `HAVING` to apply criteria after a `GROUP BY` clause.

This appears to work:

```
SELECT *, max(deleted) as md FROM
  ((SELECT *, 0 AS deleted FROM song)
UNION
  (SELECT * FROM editedsong)) AS song
-- WHERE song.deleted!=1
GROUP BY song.id
HAVING md != 1
```

This returns the record from `song`, not the record from `editedsong` for records that haven't been deleted.  If you want the other, reverse the order of the items in the `UNION` clause.

This syntax for `GROUP BY` is unusual, and I'm surprised it's supported. Most database systems I've worked with require **every** field in the output to have some treatment specified (`MAX`, `COUNT`, `GROUP BY`, etc). So a `SELECT *` is incompatible with `GROUP BY`. MySQL must be making some assumption or have some default behaviours here, but I think most servers wouldn't like it (me either).

Comment: The solution provided here seems to have solved it. I will read up on `GROUP BY`. How can I avoid doing this if it isn't the "right" way of doing it?